# AIR compilation with adt failed while executing: strip

Tags: ios, air

this one is for other users, since I solved this since.

Two main causes are :

1. Not using Air 3.0
2. Run adt on a project in Dropbox, somehow Dropbox interacts badly and makes strip.exe fail.

T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem as well, when using a project from Dropbox. Simply trying again, or turning off Dropbox entirely did seem to help.

Good luck.